# Gnome's installed user ubuntu without me knowing its password

Tags: gnome, password, users

I created a virtual machine with vagrant. The machine is ubuntu/trusty64.
I then logged in to the machine and installed gnome desktop with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

That also created another user named "ubuntu".
[image]

When I try to "Unlock" the vagrant user so I can change its properties in the User Account screen, I am asked for the password for ubuntu. which I don't know.

Is there a password I can use? or is there a way I could be prompted for the vagrant user password? (which I know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by recovery-mode.

Boot your computer to recovery-mode, start a root session and type:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd ubuntu
```

It will ask you to type and repeat the password you prefer.

If vagrant is admin user, you will not need to enter recovery mode. Just type in a terminal session:

```
sudo passwd ubuntu
```

Comment: I don't need to change the password for vagrant. 
It is the password for the user "ubuntu" that I don't know but am required by the user.

Comment: Ok, at recovery-mode, you can change ubuntu password.

Comment: I edited my answer. Look at it

Comment: Is there a point for doing it in recovery-mode. I am able to log-in just fine and also to ssh?

Comment: I ended up just doing  
sudo passwd ubuntu and it worked :)
You walked me to it thanks. update your answer so I can reward you.

Comment: Recovery-mode will give you a menu where you will see a "root" option. Got to there. You cannot access it by ssh in recovey-mode, because services will not be started there.